# Centos is killing share server

Tags: centos, gnome, indexing

I have a `centos 7` based webserver that must access (and display) pdf files from `windows share` server.

Problem is that its killing webserwer even when webacess is idle (apache stoped). I have figured out (maybe I'm wrong) that this is most likely gnome problem that has a tracker this is what I did:

1. added exclusion in PRUNEPATCHS (this worked for some time)
2. disabled all search in gnome (by clicking)
3. stoped gnome: `service gdm stop`
4. `sudo tracker stautus` say all is indexed, or gives D-Bus / X11 / $DISPLAY error (usually it works from gnome terminal, but not putty terminal)

Unplugging server network cable stops problem immediately :). Restarting works for some time.

Comment: I do not understand. If `apache` is the webserver, then it is logical that the webserver is not running when `apache` is not running.  If it is just the display-part that is going wrong, please explain how the PDFs are displayed. Otherwise it makes no sense to blame gnome. Also, what is in the logs?

Comment: I have stopped apache, but it did not stop the problem, while cutting line did - so this is how I'm sure the linux its selef is problem, but not webserwer itself. (pdfs are display by readfile from windows webshare mounted into linux). I'm 90% sure gnome is problem becouse I had cenots (same verion) without gnome and there was no problem. (as a matter of fact I have 2 machines now both with gnome and both do the same - try do index huge respository from windows share - killing the server)